# How much blood money needs to be paid (and by who) if a person is killed by a stone falling from a building's surface covered by stone?

Tags: shiism, diyya

We are living in a 5 floor building near a main street in city.

The building's surface is covered by stone (Travertine) and is in dominant position on the sidewalk.

The question is:

How much does it cost and who has to pay the blood money if one piece of the stones for no reason fall on one's head and cause him to die?

Answer (score 1):

**An interesting question!**

Based on what I perceived of the question, the answer can be as follow: it seems that the owner of the building, and probably, the exact home/floor's owner might to be the unwanted responsible for that! Since, probably its cause would be that he/she ought to buy/make a safe/firm house!

Of course I assume the municipality might be as another guilty for giving the licence/authority for such unsafe building! But, logically, it is not the fault of the owner in natural phenomena.

How much does it cost? To the best of my knowledge, apparently, it is around 1.900.000.000 Rials  or 190.000.000 of Iran's currency (as a Shia Islamic country), you can change it!

God willing, never such event happens!

**Update:**
I asked it from an engineer, he replied to me that it is the fault of supervisor-engineer as the main answerable person in charge of that event.